# How can I transform a link to a file name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a Google spreadsheet file with almost 2000 rows of URL such as this one:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B4ptELk-D3USblk1aWd1OWowRWs
```

Each URL contains an image, stored in Google Drive. My question is: How can I transform this link ( `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B4ptELk-D3USblk1aWd1OWowRWs`) to a file name? For instance, I would like to know if it could be a `/something/folder/Photofile1.jpg`.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Try using scripts: [Drive App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), [related Q on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684098/how-to-make-a-list-on-google-spreadsheet-of-all-files-in-a-google-drive-folder)

Comment: This excel corresponds to a form. Each row, has the URL (picture) of an unique item. Listing all the files is not enough, because I will not be able to map each row to it's correspondant URL (thus loosing the useful information of each row).

Comment: Please, give the access to any file, so I could test the script. My files have link like: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/  key ...` so I'm not sure the code would work with link: `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=...`

Comment: Link for the shared image: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B4ptELk-D3USVi1NZ3ZGbkhqYXc  - You can also check the sample document at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hCJA7zo6zd73WIHKGgie1QH1ZEmMmi5FwirNLEAkcrs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try script:

```
function TESTgetFileName() {
  Logger.log(getFileName('0B4ptELk-D3USVi1NZ3ZGbkhqYXc'));
  //                      ^^^^^^^^^^ file ID ^^^^^^^^^
}


function getFileName(id) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var fileName = file.getName();    
  var strFolders = getFolders(file); 
  return strFolders + '/' + fileName;  
}

function getFolders(object) {

  var folders = object.getParents();
  if (!folders.hasNext()) { return 'My Drive'; } 
  var folder = folders.next();

  var folderNames = [];

  while (folder.getParents().hasNext()) {        
    var folderName = folder.getName();
    folderNames.unshift(folderName);
    folder = folder.getParents().next();
  }

  return folderNames.join('/');

}
```

Script function will return the result:

`0B4ptELk-D3USVi1NZ3ZGbkhqYXc  →  My Drive/something/folder/Photofile1.jpg`

**Tests**

I opened script editor, selected function `TESTgetFileName` and get the result

`My Drive/Detalhes_Farmacia.Fotografia_Fachada_1.JPEG`.

This function can be run from script, not directly from spreadsheets. When you try using it as custom formula from sheet, it throws error:

> You do not have permission to call getFileById (line 8).

So better use it from script to get data and then write the result to the sheet.

Comment: I ran the script. I get the following error when I try the TESTgetFileName and the getFileName:  "You do not have permission to call getFileById (line 8)." For the getFolders I get the following: ´TypeError: Cannot find function getParents in object 0B4ptELk-D3USVi1NZ3ZGbkhqYXc. (line 16).´

Comment: I've tested the function. See **Tests** in the answer

Comment: Indeed, it works from the script editor. Is there anyway to have it working on the sheet? I have almost 2000 rows with links, it will be hard to run one by one. If there is a way to run on the sheet, I can display the result in a colum B next to the URL in column A.

Comment: No, but you can handle it with script: get all 2000 rows data into script array, then just run through array elements, get file names and then write the result into sheet.

Comment: It works. Thank you for your support. However, in terms of efficiency, it will take "forever". Each row can has an average of 4 pictures, multiplied by 2000 rows, it will be a nightmare to pass it all to the script editor and then to copy each column result and copy in the sheet. There must be an easier way to use a function on the sheet that can "call" your script and return the result at a given cell on the sheet. Is there any limitation for this?

Comment: Of course, you don't need to run every value manually. Use standart functions: `SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName(...)`, `sheet.getRange(...)`, `range.getValues()`. Learn more here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app. The goal of SO is to give answers on particular questions, not to make all code work for you.

Comment: If you'll have any problem, please post another specific question. Please mark the answer as correct, if it matches the question.